# Как настроить локальную БД в проекте Unity на Android: Entity Framework + Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: c#, android, unity3d, sqlite, entity-framework

Хотел использовать `Entity Framework` для работы с локальной БД. Изначально предполагал использовать `SQLite`, благо инструкций много. Но `SQLite` не поддерживает подход `Code First`.

Пишут, что для Code First требуется СУБД от Microsoft.

- Возможно ли использовать MS SQL Server в качестве локальной БД на Андроид по аналогии с SQLite?
- Или SQLite - это единственный вариант?

Comment: Не знаю сработает ли на телефоне, но я в своем desktop приложении использовал sql server compact, code first, полет нормальный.

Answer (score 1):

В теории можно развернуть СУБД на смартфоне, но на практике такого извращения не видел.

Для реализации Code First для SQLite воспользуйтесь [библиотекой](https://github.com/msallin/SQLiteCodeFirst).

Answer (score 1):

У меня нет опыта работы с MS SQL на андроид напрямую, однако я всё же выскажусь в ответе, потому что полагаю, что таковых людей в природе может и не найтись. Ну вот например, на хабре [статья](https://habr.com/en/post/206790/), в которой рассматривается близкий случай - MS SQL в локальной сети.

Мой ответ вот какой: работать с локальной MS SQL базой на андроид невозможно. Чисто гипотетически, андроид - это линукс, а под линуксом можно установить и запустить MS SQL сервер. Но есть два больших "но":

- теоретическое: [список](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup?view=sql-server-2017) поддерживаемых вендором платформ не включает андроид
- практическое: ограничения по оперативной памяти. Если мне не изменяет память, там фигурирует "от 2 гб", но я лично пробовал ставить ms sql под centos - так вот не хочет инсталлятор запускаться, да и на слегка больших объёмах работает так себе. Вряд ли типичный пользователь мобильника захочет запускать такое прожорливое приложение на телефоне, а на бюджетных моделях просто не установится

Так что посмотрите в сторону альтернативных вариантов. Но вообще - телефон плохое место для сервера, на нём лучше держать легковесную базу, которая при необходимости может синхронизироваться с мощным сервером.

Answer (score 1):

SQLite поддерживает подход Code First. Я использую библиотеку [SQLite-Net](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net) и проектирую классы, а не структуру БД. При создании коннекта вызываю SQLiteConnection.CreateTable<мой класс>, в результате таблица создается, либо, если она уже есть, добавляются новые поля, а данные сохраняются.

Насчет MS SQL Server на Android - думаю, что это намного сложнее, если вообще получится.